# Are there any problems crossing Kosovo's international borders or having their stamp in your passport?

Tags: passports, borders, serbia, passport-stamps, kosovo

I'm thinking of heading from Romania to Serbia to Albania, possibly via Kosovo (on an Australian passport).

Since Kosovo becoming a country wasn't unanimously popular in the region I'm a bit concerned that Serbia or Albania might not fully approve of me visiting Kosovo. Are there any border crossing difficulties for tourists, or will having a Kosovo stamp in my passport cause issues when entering neighbouring countries? (Do all Kosovo's neighbours even recognize Kosovo?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Officially it varies - the UN doesn't recognise Kosovo, but several others do.  The big problem for you, as you observed - is Serbia, which considers it to be another province, and indeed administers five of the municipalities.

The best warning I can find seems to come from Wikitravel:

Visa Restrictions:

Serbia officially states that it will block passports containing stamps or visas from Kosovo. However, in practice, immigration officers would usually just [cancel the Kosovan stamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kosovan_passport#/media/File:Kosovo_stamp_annulled_by_Serbia.jpg) and replace them with Serbian ones.

> If you are just visiting the region, visit Serbia first. You will not
>   be given a Serbian exit stamp if you enter Kosovo from Serbia. If you
>   are living in or intend to travel frequently to Serbia, you should get
>   matching pairs of entry and exit stamps; this would mean backtracking
>   and leaving through Serbia via a regular border crossing point. If you
>   travel a lot in the region, your passport will be crowded with stamps
>   anyway and border guards may not be able to find the matching stamps,
>   and normally let you pass. Just avoid mentioning Kosovo. You can ask
>   Kosovar authorities not to stamp your passport at the border.

So unless you obsess with stamps (which I can empathise with), the simplest solution would be to ask them not to stamp the passport, much like many travellers do with Israel.

Comment: I don't collect passport stamps but I've had trouble once in Central America where one of many border guards/immigration officials forgot to stamp me into one country which I only found out as I was leaving it for the next country. I should be going into Kosovo from Serbia and out the other side into Albania so it looks like it might be OK. Thanks.

Comment: @hippietrail I think this can be trouble if you are again visit Serbia.

Comment: @VMAtm: I should be heading east from Albania to the Republic of Georgia and don't expect to be back in Serbia any time soon. Might need a new passport anyway by that stage since it's getting pretty full now.

Comment: @hippietrail Good luck with that then.

Answer (score 5):

Going from Romania into Serbia, then into Kosovo and on to Albania should be no problem at all.

The only problematic situation I know of is moving from a third country into Kosovo and then into Serbia and finally leave to another country. This is because when entering Serbia through Kosovo you don't get a Serbian entry stamp and therefor have not entered legally.

Some friends of mine did exactly that and when they left Serbia for Hungary the immigration officials just crossed out the Kosovo stamp.

When travelling from Serbia into Kosovo you usually don't get a Kosovo entry stamp but you may get a Kosovo exit stamp when you leave.

I have entry stamps but no corresponding exit stamps for several Balkan countries including Serbia.

Answer (score 4):

I went to Kosovo 4 times in 2011, got two stamps 3 times, once they forgot one. Serbians are not so good with stamping, I didn't get one when leaving to Bulgaria. That means that you can just ask the Kosovars not to stamp your passport when you leave Kosovo once you entered it from Serbia.

What is important to remember is that entering Serbia from Kosovo after entering the latter from a 3rd country may prove impossible or problematic. I read an account of a Polish cyclist who was refused entry to Serbia although some German cyclists in front of him were allowed to enter. Afterwards, he was smuggled in by Polish peacekeeping soldiers through a green border into Serbia :) I met those same soldiers one day in Macedonia when they were on a weekend off and they confirmed this story.

So... even when you are refused entry to Serbia after entering Kosovo from a third country, you still stand a chance if you meet Polish KFOR! ;-)

Comment: "Serbians are not so good with stamping, I didn't get one when leaving to Bulgaria" They don't stamp foreign passports on exit, only on entry. For Serbian passports it's the other way round

Answer (score 3):

Bumping old post:

Having Kosovar stamps is not a Problem: **however**, if using a passport, you cannot enter Kosovo from Montenegro or Macedonia, or by air, and then continue to Serbia - you can only travel from Serbia to Kosovo and then back.

To be exact: on the way from Kosovo to Serbia, there will be one Kosovar exit check, and then a Serbian entry check. The Serbians will then refuse you entry if you don't have a current Serbian entry stamp (which is only possible if you entered Serbia from a third country and then went to Kosovo)

There is one way around this rule, though it's only possible for (most) European nationals: using an ID card instead of a passport. They cannot be stamped, so the Serbs cannot prove how you entered Kosovo.

However, the ID card must be one accepted for entry to Serbia, i.e. from an EU country, Bosnia, Macedonia, Montenegro or Switzerland (or, of course, Serbia or Kosovo)

Bosnian ID cards are valid for Serbia but not for Kosovo so Bosnian citizens must be careful to use the passport for the Kosovar check, and the ID card for the Serbian check

Answer (score 2):

I traveled to Serbia and then Macedonia before going to Kosovo. I was on a bus from Kosovo to Bosnia. Serbia did not like my Kosovo passport stamp. Another passenger asked them to please let me and my two kids into Serbia.

It was a dark night and I could see a tank. I was so very scared. I am so happy they did let me in. Good luck to all other travelers.

Comment: If you're European, use a national ID card for such a trip next time (unless you're Danish, Norwegian, Icelandic or British, because they don't have them)