# Can I enter Kosovo with EU ID card?

Tags: passports, eu-citizens, serbia, kosovo

Since June 2010 EU citizens can enter Serbia with ID card. I wonder if I can also enter Kosovo with ID card?

Comment: Do you think it's for EU citizens or Schengen area citizens? I found only a resource confusing EU and Schengen : http://www.scb.travel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=231:eu-citizens-can-enter-serbia-without-passport&catid=36:vesti&Itemid=104

Comment: @Vince EU +  Switzerland, Norway and Iceland. I'm from Bulgaria and we're not part of the Schengen area, but I can enter Serbia with my ID card.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. Starting from May 8, 2013 every EU citizen can enter to Kosovo with ID card only, as mentioned on the [Kosovo Ministry of Foreign Affairs website](http://www.mfa-ks.net/?page=2,20) (at the bottom of the page)

Answer (score 4):

Kosovo has not yet defined [a particular policy on this topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Kosovo).

According to [its Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa-ks.net/?page=2,20), there is no distinction based on the citizenship. Every citizen may therefore enter the country and stay for a maximum of 90 days. However, there are some rules to respect. You should be able to :

- Have some valid travel documents (thus coming from a not recognized country may be an issue)
- Prove you can pay for your expenses
- Prove you will exit the territory (for example, having a return ticket)
- Give a reason for travelling to Kosovo

After 90 days, a traveller must contact the Kosovo police to be registered, but it is unclear if the right to stay will be granted.

EDIT : See @Janusz answer, as the policy is now defined and EU citizens can enter with an ID card.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Bulgarian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.bg/120/findanembassy/0/179), as a Bulgarian citizen you need a valid Bulgarian passport to enter Kosovo.

For citizens from other EU countries it is analogical. They need a valid passport of their home country. I have checked the sites of several ministries of foreign affairs. They all say the same thing.

P.S. [This information](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/4501/3470) might be relevant too, although it is not directly linked to your question.