# Serbia - Kosovo border problem?

Tags: passports, borders, serbia, kosovo

I would like to travel onto Balkans' quartro Serbia, Bosnia Herzegovina, then Montenegro and Kosovo with my Turkish passport as both countries do not require Visa. The problem that concerns me is Serbian - Kosovo border. Is there any problem getting into Serbia from Kosovo? What should I do?

There's some information on the internet which confuses me. They are telling entering to Kosovo from Novi Pazar (SER) shouldn't be a problem but the opposite is the biggest problem. They are telling that I shouldn't let any Kosovan stamp on my password. But wouldn't it make this travel illegal? If I can't find a solution, unfortunately I have to cancel visiting Kosovo where I would like to visit the most.

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/are-there-any-problems-crossing-kosovos-international-borders-or-having-their-s

Comment: if you enter Kosovo from Serbia and then go back to Serbia it should be ok. is that your plan?

Answer (score 8):

The Embassy of Sweden in Pristina has some information regarding travelling to and from Kosovo on its homepage. It is could certainly be applied to travellers with other nationalities as well.

> **In- och utresebestämmelser**
>   EU-medborgare är sedan 8 maj 2013 tillåtna att vid in- och utresa i
>   Kosovo presentera en giltig identitetshandling i form av ordinarie
>   pass, diplomatpass, tjänstepass alternativt ID-kort.
>
> **Gränspassage**
>   Kosovos gränskontroller erkänns inte av Serbien.
>   Passkontrollerna i Kosovo stämplar sedan juli 2008 vid in- och utresa.
>   Stämpeln har texten "Republic of Kosovo". Vid inresa till Serbien via
>   Kosovo kan en sådan inresestämpel utfärdad av Kosovo Police betraktas
>   som ogiltig och den resande nekas inträde. Andra resrutter till
>   Serbien är därför att föredra.
>
> Detta innebär att det inte är möjligt att resa in i Kosovo med flyg
>   eller landvägen via Makedonien, Montenegro eller Albanien för att
>   sedan till Serbien. Däremot går det bra att resa från Serbien in i
>   Kosovo och åter.
>
> Kosovos myndigheter har inga restriktioner för tillresande från
>   Serbien.
>
> Ditt pass måste vara giltigt sex månader efter inresedatum.

My translation:

> **Entry and outward jorneys**
>   Since May 8 2013, EU nationals are allowed at the entry and exit of Kosovo present a valid identity
>   document in the form of ordinary passport, diplomatic passport,
>   service passport alternative ID cards.
>
> **Border crossing**
>   Kosovo's border controls are not recognized by Serbia. Passport control in Kosovo stamps since July 2008 the passport
>   upon entry and exit. The stamp bears the words "Republic of Kosovo".
>   On entry into Serbia via Kosovo, such an entry stamp issued by the
>   Kosovo Police is considered invalid and the traveller is refused
>   entry. Other itineraries for Serbia is therefore preferable.
>
> This means that it is not possible to travel into Kosovo by air or
>   overland through Macedonia, Montenegro or Albania and then to Serbia.
>   However, it is possible to travel from Serbia into Kosovo and again.
>
> Kosovo authorities have no restrictions on travellers from Serbia.
>
> Your passport must be valid for six months from the date of entry.