# Applying for a Kosovo tourist visa from India

Tags: visas, consulates, bangladeshi-citizens, kosovo

I am planning to visit Kosovo. I am from Bangladesh, currently staying in New Delhi, India. I don't know where the Kosovo Embassy in India is, nor where I apply for a visa.

Comment: Considering India doesn't recognize Kosovo I don't see this possible in New Delhi.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_Kosovo

Answer (score 5):

**Sorry, that visa is going to be pretty tough to get**.  [You are required to get a visa for Kosovo in advance and applications must be made in person](http://www.ambasada-ks.net/jp/?page=2,82).  The nearest embassies from India are in [Japan](http://www.ambasada-ks.net/jp/?page=2,80), [Saudi Arabia](http://www.ambasada-ks.net/?page=2,3&value=8&type=) and [Turkey](http://www.ambasada-ks.net/?page=2,3&value=9&type=0), each of which *also* require visas for Bangladeshi citizens.

That said, the answer to [this previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/42298/i-am-travelling-from-india-to-kosovo-via-turkey-do-i-need-a-visa-as-an-indian) indicates that applying via mail *is* possible, so I recommend you get in touch with one of those embassies and see what they say.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer of jpatokal, the [website of the Brussels embassy](http://www.ambasada-ks.net/be/?page=5,49) states

> Foreign citizens, subject to visa regime application, but bearers of valid multiple entry Schengen visa may enter the Republic of Kosovo and stay up to 15 days without having to obtain a Kosovo visa.

This might be an option if your Kosovo stay is part of a Europe trip or in between other European travels.
However, I was not able to confirm this information from the websites of the other embassies (I didn't check all of them, just a not very random sample). If you would go for this option, it appears wise to look for additional confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

Foreigners who possess a valid multiple-entry Schengen visa don't need to obtain a Kosovo visa to enter, transit or stay in the territory of the Republic of Kosovo for up to 15 days, within a period of 6 months.

For more information, please have a look at these resources:

- [Non-Schengen Area countries where you can GO with a Schengen VISA](http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/non-eu-countries-where-you-can-go-with-schengen-visa/)
- [Kosovo Visa Application Requirements, Procedures and Guideliness](http://aab-edu.net/en/about-aab/welcome-to-kosovo/kosovo-visa-application-requirements-procedures-guideliness/)

Comment: @pnuts when a person takes the effort of travelling so far, they usually see more than one tiny area, and in the neighbourhood most countries are in Schengen.

Answer (score 2):

According to [VisaHQ](https://kosovo.visahq.in/requirements/Bangladesh/resident-India/):

> Kosovo tourist visa is not required for citizens of Bangladesh for a stay up to 90 days.

However, [IATA](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/RK--customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-summary.htm) seems to indicate that a visa is required and the KLM version of [TIMATIC](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/travel_planning/travel_clinic/visaform.htm) appears not to know of Kosovo.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisaHQ):

> VisaHQ maintains the world's most comprehensive database of international visa requirements).

However, it seems it may have failed to update part of it over the past 3½   years (up until 1 July 2013 Kosovo did not require visas for anyone).  [CITB UK](http://cibtvisas.co.uk/requirements) has:

> Yes, a visa is required to travel to this country.

It has proved very reliable though at times slightly overstates the requirements (for example may fail to mention that visa on arrival is available). However the site goes on to mention:

> The embassy requires the applicant to apply for a visa in person.

Which is clearly not practical for someone based in New Delhi (according to [Embassy Worldwide](http://www.embassy-worldwide.com/country/kosovo/) there is a Kosovo Embassy in UK, but no embassy or consulate for Kosovo in India).

The [CIBT USA](http://cibtvisas.com/visas?source=delivers_homepage) is less helpful, with the only choice for purpose of trip being "Connecting/Transit".

So it may be worth contacting Embassy of the Republic of Kosovo in London:

Address: Rr. John 8
London WC1N 2ES UK
e-mail:  visa.london@rks-gov.net
http://www.ambasada-ks.net/gb

(London because English is more likely to be understood there) and seeking clarification of (a) what is required and (b) if a visa is, where and how to apply when based in India.

Comment: Why do you think the London embassy will tell something different than what is on their website (http://www.kosovoembassy.org.uk/?page=2,100): "You need a visa to visit or transit Kosovo." (with the exception of mentioned multiple entry Schengen visa and some more)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as a Bangladesh citizen, you need a visa:
http://www.mfa-ks.net/?page=2,102

> Bangladesh
>
> You need a visa to visit or transit Kosovo.
>
> Visas may be obtained from diplomatic and consular posts of Kosovo in:
>
> ```
> Tirana, Albania
> Ambasada e Republikës së Kosovës në Tiranë
> Rr. Donika Kastrioti, Vila nr 6, Tiranë
> E-mail : visa.al@rks-gov.net
> http://www.ambasada-ks.net/al/
>
> Istanbul, Turkey
> Konsullata e Përgjithshme e Republikës së Kosovës në Stamboll
> Vali Konağı Cad. No: 74 D 3
> Nişantaşı, İstanbul / Turkey
> E-mail: visa.ist@rks-gov.net
> http://www.ambasada-ks.net/tr/
> ```
>
> Please note that you do not need a visa to visit or transit Kosovo,
>   if:
>
> - You are a holder of a valid biometric residence permit issued by one of the Schengen member states or a valid multi-entry Schengen Visa
>     (max. 15 days stay)
> - You are a holder of a valid Laissez-Passer issued by United Nations Organizations, NATO, OSCE, Council of Europe or European Union
> - You are a holder of a valid travel documents issued by EU Member and Schengen States, United States of America, Canada, Australia and Japan
>     based on the 1951 Convention on Refugee Status or the 1954 Convention
>     on the Status of Stateless Persons, as well as holders of valid travel
>     documents for foreigners (max. 15 days stay)

You can apply in the following consulate:
http://www.mfa-ks.net/?page=2,166